# Using an input variable in a list field in a GCP Workflow

Tags: dataform, google-workflows

I'm trying to set the `includedTags` via a variable when creating a GCP Dataform Workflow Invocation via GCP Workflows. My relevant GCP Workflows step is:

```yaml
main:
    params: [args]
    steps:
    - createWorkflowInvocation:
        try:
            call: http.post
            args:
                url: https://dataform.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/<endpoint>
                auth:
                    type: OAuth2
                body:
                    compilationResult: <cr>
                    invocationConfig:
                        includedTags: [args.DATAFORM_TAGS]
```

where `args.DATAFORM_TAGS` is a comma-separated string such as `alerting,daily`. This is based on the [Dataform docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/schedule-executions-workflows) (although notice that the docs put each tag on a separate line).

This fails with the error:

> {"error":{"code":400,"message":"At least one action must be selected for execution.","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}

`args.DATAFORM_TAGS` isn't being substituted properly. I've confirmed that the variable is being correctly set (I can print it out in a different step).

I think that the problem is with `args.DATAFORM_TAGS` being within square brackets. If I replace that line with `includedTags: [alerting,daily]` then it works. I've tried various other things such as:

- `includedTags: [${args.DATAFORM_TAGS}]`
- `includedTags: ${"[" + args.DATAFORM_TAGS + "]"}`
- `includedTags: text.split(args.DATAFORM_TAGS, ",")`
- `includedTags: text.split("alerting,daily", ",")`
- sending the body as a JSON message rather than letting GCP Workflows convert directly

but none work.

Comment: I'm not sure if you could set `includedTags` to a dynamic value because based on this [documentation on `invocationConfig`](https://cloud.google.com/dataform/reference/rest/v1beta1/InvocationConfig), it only accepts `string` as a value. You can also check the format [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/schedule-executions-workflows#customize_the_sql_workflow_invocation_request). Hope these help.

Comment: @RobertG thanks. `includedTags: [alerting,daily]` works but `includedTags: [args.DATAFORM_TAGS]` doesn't, there should be no difference between these two as `args.DATAFORM_TAGS` resolves to a string

Comment: I think GCP Workflows adds quotes when it does the variable substitution, so `includedTags: [args.DATAFORM_TAGS]` becomes `includedTags: ["alerting,daily"]`, then Dataform thinks it's looking for one tag named `alerting,daily` and fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`includedTags: ${text.split(args.DATAFORM_TAGS, ",")}` works. It's not far from some other solutions that I'd tried, the key thing that I was missing is the `${}` wrapping around it.

The full working code:

```
main:
    params: [args]
    steps:
    - createWorkflowInvocation:
        try:
            call: http.post
            args:
                url: https://dataform.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/<endpoint>
                auth:
                    type: OAuth2
                body:
                    compilationResult: <cr>
                    invocationConfig:
                        includedTags: ${text.split(args.DATAFORM_TAGS, ",")}
```